# Google Calendar is ignoring silent mode

Tags: notifications

I'm having an issue with the Google Calendar app, specifically its notifications. It ignores the sound profile of the phone. For example, if my phone is silenced, it still makes its notification sound. This isn't an issue with any other app, just Google Calendar.

The device is a Moto X 2013 running CyanogenMod 12.1 on the last stable release that is available (which, I continue to find, is a sad excuse for a stable release).

Does anyone have an ideas on how to stop this? Turning off all notifications for the app is not a possibility and I've tried resetting its cache already.

Comment: I've found this too.  I uninstalled it :/

Comment: @Matthew Read as a college student, that's unfortunelty not an option. I need Google calendar.